# Sql query error in laravel Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying retrive subjects name from subjects table of my database.but it gives a error calling property[id] does not exist on this collection instance.error occur when i use code as belows

{{ $subjects->id}}

but this way not gives a error

{{ $subjects}}

code of the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Subject;
use PDF;

class report1dataController extends Controller
{

public function reportPdf()
{
   $subjects = DB::table('subjects')->get();
   $pdf  = PDF::loadview('reports1', ['subjects' => $subjects]); 



   return $pdf->download('report.pdf');
}

  public function report()
    {

         $subjects = DB::table('subjects')->get();

        return view('reports1', ['subjects' => $subjects]);
    }
}
```

codes of blade.php

```
<body>
<h1><a href="{{url('/pdfs1')}}" > Download pdf</a></h1>
<table>
<caption>Student Details</caption>
<tr>

<td> subject    </td>


</tr>
@foreach($subjects as $subject)

<tr><td>{{ $subjects}} </td></tr>




@endforeach

</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below, you are iterating `$subjects` which will give you `$subject` as an item of object on every loop

```
@foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <tr><td>{{ $subject->id}} </td></tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: glad to help you , you can mark it as correct answer if it really helped you.

Comment: <tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>subject </td>



</tr>


<tr>
@foreach($subjects as $subject)
<td>{{ $subject->id}} </td>
<td>{{ $subject->subject}}</td>
@endforeach

</tr>

Comment: but there is a problem .when i try above way all the data in a one row

Comment: all data in a one row? I didnt get you

Comment: when data shows in the browser they shows in one row."1 sinhala 2 Science ". these all are in one row

Comment: you mean to say that it has only one data?

Comment: i am sorry.i used <tr> tag in wrong way.thank you very much .